# Getting error while passing event.target.value in angular ts

Tags: html, angular, typescript

My app.component.html code is :

```
    <h1>Password Generator</h1>
<div>
<label>Length</label>
</div>
<input (input)="onChangeLength($event.target.value)"/>
<div>
<div>
  <input (change)="onChangeHandlerLetter()" type="checkbox" />
  <label>Use Letter</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input (change)="onChangeHandlerNumbers()" type="checkbox" />
  <label>Use Numbers</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input (change)="onChangeHandlerSymbols()" type="checkbox" />
  <label>Use Symbols</label>
</div>
<div>
  <button (click)="onButtonClick()">Generate</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Your Password</label>
</div>
<input [value]="password"/>

{{password}}
```

My app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  length=0;
  includeLetters=false;
  includeSymbols=false;
  includeNumbers=false
  onChangeHandlerLetter=()=>{
    this.includeLetters=!this.includeLetters
  }
  onChangeHandlerSymbols=()=>{
    this.includeSymbols=!this.includeSymbols
  }
  onChangeHandlerNumbers=()=>{
    this.includeNumbers=!this.includeNumbers
  }
  onChangeLength=(val:string)=>{
    const parsedValue=parseInt(val);
    if(!isNaN(parsedValue)){
      this.length=parsedValue
    }
    console.log(length);
  }
  password=" "
  onButtonClick=()=>{
  this.password="My Password"
  console.log("button clicked");
  console.log(`Following should be included :
              Sybmols : ${this.includeSymbols}
              Numbers : ${this.includeNumbers}
              Letters : ${this.includeLetters}`)
 }

}
```

error :

```
index.js:561 [webpack-dev-server] ERROR
src/app/app.component.html:5:46 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

5 <input (input)="onChangeLength($event.target.value)"/>
                                               ~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

Hello greetings community , I am new to TS and angular so I dont know why I am getting this error I need to take input from input bar and change into number and console.log I am following a tutorial and he is getting correct output I dont know why

Comment: hi! that issue is because when input starts it has no value or when you delete all the characters, so the event lauch by the event can be null. You can use two thigs. try with this `onChangeLength($event.target?.value)` or try by only sending $event `onChangeLength($event)` and checking on the code inside onChangeLength if the event is receiving a value

Comment: did but getting 0 in console.log? what does that means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell TypeScript the type of the `HTMLElement` which is your target.

To do so instead of $event.target.value please use $event as below:

```
<input (input)="onChangeLength($event)"/>
```

then in app.component.ts use:

```
const parsedValue=parseInt((<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value);
```

Working codes:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ColdObservable } from 'rxjs/internal/testing/ColdObservable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  length=0;
  includeLetters=false;
  includeSymbols=false;
  includeNumbers=false
  onChangeHandlerLetter=()=>{
    this.includeLetters=!this.includeLetters
  }
  onChangeHandlerSymbols=()=>{
    this.includeSymbols=!this.includeSymbols
  }
  onChangeHandlerNumbers=()=>{
    this.includeNumbers=!this.includeNumbers
  }
  onChangeLength=( event: Event)=>{
    
     const parsedValue=parseInt((<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value);
     if(!isNaN(parsedValue)){
       this.length=parsedValue
     }
     console.log(length);
  }
  password=" "
  onButtonClick=()=>{
  this.password="My Password"
  console.log("button clicked");
  console.log(`Following should be included :
              Sybmols : ${this.includeSymbols}
              Numbers : ${this.includeNumbers}
              Letters : ${this.includeLetters}`)
 }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>Password Generator</h1>
<div>
<label>Length</label>
</div>
<input (input)="onChangeLength($event)"/>
<div>
<div>
  <input (change)="onChangeHandlerLetter()" type="checkbox" />
  <label>Use Letter</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input (change)="onChangeHandlerNumbers()" type="checkbox" />
  <label>Use Numbers</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input (change)="onChangeHandlerSymbols()" type="checkbox" />
  <label>Use Symbols</label>
</div>
<div>
  <button (click)="onButtonClick()">Generate</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label>Your Password</label>
</div>
<input [value]="password"/>

{{password}}
```

Comment: Oshadharon bhai Angular o suru kore felsen